# Embedding of moduli space of J-holomorphic spheres into moduli space of stable maps

Tags: symplectic-geometry, moduli-space

Let $(M,\omega)$ be a closed symplectic manifold of dimension $2m$, $J$ be an $\omega$-compatible almost complex structure, and $A\in H_2(M;\mathbb{Z})$ a homology class. Let $n \geq 3$ and denote by $\mathcal{M}_{0,n}(A;J)$ be the moduli space of $J$-holomorphic spheres and $\overline{\mathcal{M}}_{0,n}(A;J)$ the moduli space of stable $J$-holomorphic maps (of genus zero) representing $A$.
I am wondering whether the inclusion $\mathcal{M}_{0,n}(A;J)\rightarrow \overline{\mathcal{M}}_{0,n}(A;J)$ induces an isomorphism in compactly supported $\check{C}$ech cohomology in the degree of the virtual dimension?

Comment: In general, this is not true, because the moduli space of smooth maps can be empty while the moduli of stable maps is not. Local CY 3-folds will give you example of what you want. (Also, this question is probably more appropriate for Mathoverflow).

Comment: Thank you very much!